# No polynomial of degree 3 in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I prove that no polynomial of degree 3 in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of polynomials with real coefficients is a prime?

I really need help on this one guys. I know I need to use the Intermediate Value Theorem but I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: Leave your question in the original form. That way people with the same problem don't have to ask

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.  It will help others to understand what the answers are about.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and assume, WLOG (without loss of generality), that $a>0$.

Then

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =+\infty$$

(WLOG since if $a<0$ then we still get one infinite and one negative infinite limit, which is all we need)

So $f(x)$ takes on positive and negative values, otherwise it couldn't approach $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively, hence has a zero by the IVT since $0$ is between any positive and negative number. Since it is a polynomial, this means it factors as $(x-r)(a'x^2+b'x+c')$, i.e. it is reducible. This is seen because all real polynomials factor over $\Bbb C$, and since $f(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$ for every complex $x$, the only way to have a product of three things be $0$ is if one of them is zero. Since this happens for some $x\in \Bbb R$ from the IVT, we determine the polynomial has a real root.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and concise answer! Could you provide a bit of detail on the step 2nd step :" So f(x) takes on positive and negative values, hence has a zero by the IVT. Since it is a polynomial, this means it factors as (x−r)(a′x2+b′x+c′), i.e. it is reducible." I understand it has a zero by IVT but I don't understand how this relates to it being a polynomial and thus factoring as (x−r)(a′x2+b′x+c′)? Cheers

Comment: @Elliot  Those are two distinct steps. Do you want me to comment on the positive and negative for the factorization?

Comment: I think i'm starting to see better what's going on, but would you mind copy pasting the proof and just adding a few steps on the positive and negative for the factorization so I get a better idea of how it works on the whole? I had never encountered WLOG so far but it's interesting - in this case if you hadn't written WLOG how would you substitute using WLOG? Last thing, a>0 caught my eye so is that what the WLOG for is? i.e symmetry?

Comment: @Elliott I have updated my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(x)=ax^3+\text{lower-degree terms}$.  Show that if $x$ is large by comparison to $a$ and to the lower-degree coefficients, then $ax^3$ overwhelms the lower-degree terms, so that $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$ (if $a>0$) and $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$ (if $a<0$).

Since polynomial functions are continuous, if this function goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ then someone in between it is equal to $0$.  Suppose $f(k)=0$.  Now remember something from algebra: if $f(k)=0$, then $f(x)$ is divisible by $x-k$, i.e. $f(x)=(x-k)(\cdots\cdots\cdots)$, where the dots represent some second-degree polynomial.