# Proving a polynomial is prime in $ \mathbb{R}[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I had gotten this question on a recent assignment, and am confused on how to approach it. Would I need to use Gauss's Lemma?

*Prove that $t^2 + 1$ is a prime in  $ \mathbb{R}[t]$. Prove that no polynomial of degree $3$ is a prime*

Comment: No Gauss's Lemma needed.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052121/how-do-i-prove-that-no-polynomial-of-degree-3-in-the-ring-of-polynomials-with-re/1052123#1052123 for the second result.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $(t^2+1)\mid f(t)g(t)$. Then from $i^2+1=0$ we conclude $f(i)g(i)=0$, so  wlog $f(i)=0$ and by complex conjugation $f(-i)=0$. Hence in $\mathbb C[t]$, we have that $(t+i)(t-i)$ divides $f$. But $(t+i)(t-i)=t^2+1$.

Every odd degree polynomial has a real root, hence every cubic has a linear factor, is reducible, hence not prime.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $t^2+1$ could be written as the product of two non-constant polynomials, then there would have to be a linear $f(t)$ divided $t^2+1$ - but a linear function divides another polynomial if and only if the root of the linear function is a root of the polynomial. (This hint applies to the second question too)